# Dynamic CRM 2016 Word Templates - Add Current Logged in User

Tags: templates, crm, document, microsoft-dynamics

With CRM 2016, the users have the ability to create Word document using templates.
I was creating a word template in which I need to populate the logged in User name in the template.
I did not find a mapping in the XML Mapping pane which would map to the current logged in User. Is there a way I can set a mapping in the CRM word template which would allow me to get the logged in User Name in the generated word document?